# IBM WebSphere User Inactivity Timeout

Tags: session, websphere, user-inactivity

How do I set a user inactivity timeout in IBM WebSphere (Integrated Solutions Console, 7.0.0.43)?
As long as the user is actively using the WebSphere console, they should be logged in as long as they want, but if they're inactive for a certain period of time, I want them to be prompted to login once more. 
Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a default timeout set for 30 minutes.

Use the official documentation to change the ISC session timeout:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/isc/cons_sessionto.html

Alternatively you can try to edit file manually

Go to DMGR profile.In the profile home directory navigate to the following subdirectory "/config/cells//applications/isclite.ear/deployments/isclite" and open the file "deployment.xml". Modify the value "invalidationTimeout" .

src: http://orebmann.blogspot.com/2014/10/increase-session-timeout-of-websphere.html?m=1